# Code is unreachable

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Relatively new to programming but I can't work out why my If statement is unreachable. Also what would be the best way to return the calculation so I can send it back?

```
while (Reader.Read()) {
        if (Reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (Reader.Name == "Amount")
            {
                if ("Amount" == "Gold" || value > 4999)
                {
                    credit = 300;
                    DiscountPercent = .20f;     
                }
                else if ("Amount" == "Silver" || value > 4999)
                {
                    DiscountPercent = .15f;    
                }
                else if ("Amount" == "Regular")
                {
                    credit = 200;   
                }

            }
            else if (Reader.Name == "Member")
            {
                if ("Member" == "Gold" || value > 4999)
                {
                    credit = 300;
                    DiscountPercent = .20f;
                }
                else if ("Member" == "Silver" || value > 4999)
                {
                    DiscountPercent = .15f;
                }
                else if ("Member" == "Regular")
                {
                    credit = 200;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could it be because I'm not including a break statement?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with these: `"Amount" == "Gold"`? The string "Amount" will never be equal to the string "Gold", and therefore the contents of some of your `if` statements will never be run.

Comment: Why are you calling  Reader.Read(); in a while statement  using Reader.Read(); ?

Comment: Oops soory Reader.Read() was just a leftover. Ahh okay so I should store it into a variable first. Thanks guys!

Comment: It would help to specify which statement(s) is/are unreachable.

Answer (score 5):

`"Amount" == "Gold"` will never evaluate to `true`, because the strings are different. Same goes for other string comparisons. Compiler reduces this `false` out of the `||`, so it "sees" the following:

```
if (value > 4999) {
    credit = 300;
    DiscountPercent = .20f;
} else if (value > 4999) {
    DiscountPercent = .15f;
} else if (false) {
    credit = 200;
}
```

The compiler reasonably concludes that the middle and the bottom `if`s are unreachable.

To fix this code, read the value, and use it in your comparisons:

```
if (Reader.Name == "Amount") {
    var amount = Reader.Value;
    if (amount == "Gold" || value > 4999) {
        credit = 300;
        DiscountPercent = .20f;     
    } else if (amount == "Silver" || value > 4999) {
        DiscountPercent = .15f;    
    } else if (amount == "Regular") {
        credit = 200;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've re-written your code to make it compile:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
        XmlReader Reader = XmlReader.Create("items.xml", settings);
        int value = 500;
        int credit = 0;
        var DiscountPercent = 0.1f;

        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            if (Reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (Reader.Name == "Amount")
                {

                    if ("Amount" == "Gold" || value > 4999)
                    {
                        credit = 300;
                        DiscountPercent = .20f;

                    }
                    else if ("Amount" == "Silver" || value > 4999)
                    {
                        DiscountPercent = .15f;

                    }
                    else if ("Amount" == "Regular")
                    {
                        credit = 200;  //unreachable code detected
                    }
                    Reader.Read();
                }
                else if (Reader.Name == "Member")
                {
                    if ("Member" == "Gold" || value > 4999)
                    {
                        credit = 300;
                        DiscountPercent = .20f;
                    }
                    else if ("Member" == "Silver" || value > 4999)
                    {
                        DiscountPercent = .15f;
                    }
                    else if ("Member" == "Regular")
                    {
                        credit = 200;  //unreachable code detected
                    }
                    Reader.Read();
                }      
            }
        }
    }
```

I've added some suggestions to help you figure out what's going on...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("items.xml", settings);
        int value = 500;
        int credit = 0;
        var discountPercent = 0.1f;  //generally people use lower case for variables
        var amountType = "Gold";  //added this variable to replace constant
        var memberType = "Gold";  //added this variable to replace constant

        while (reader.Read())  //generally people use lower case for variables "reader.Read()"
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (reader.Name == "Amount")
                {
                    //two constant but different strings will never equal each other...
                    //, just like the integer 1 will never equal 2
                    if ("Amount" == amountType || value > 4999)  
                    {
                        credit = 300; 
                        discountPercent = .20f;

                    }
                    else if ("Amount" == amountType || value > 4999)
                    {
                        discountPercent = .15f;

                    }
                    else if ("Amount" == amountType)
                    {
                        credit = 200;  //no error, code is now reachable
                    }
                    reader.Read();
                }
                else if (reader.Name == "Member")
                {
                    if ("Member" == memberType || value > 4999)
                    {
                        credit = 300;
                        discountPercent = .20f;
                    }
                    else if ("Member" == memberType || value > 4999)
                    {
                        discountPercent = .15f;
                    }
                    else if ("Member" == memberType)
                    {
                        credit = 200;  //no error, code is now reachable
                    }
                    reader.Read();
                }                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's with the random `#region`?

Comment: I added it because it made it easier for me to read the code outside of that section.  Maybe that was confusing?  I removed it.